# I'm trying to output this to a table in the order of the form

Tags: perl, cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;

print header;
print start_html("Thank You");
print h2("Thank You");

my %form;
foreach my $p (param()) {
        $form{$p} = param($p);
        print "$p = $form{$p}<br>\n";
        }

print end_html;
```

This works for all basic forms and the confirmation is good but not in a table http://www.quickpaysolutions.com/tt.html

I have another form that does work with the tables but the form confirmation comes out alphabetical and not the way the form is constructed. I would like the form in table borders and in the order of the form.

http://www.quickpaysolutions.com/jt.html

The code for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
use CGI;
my $cgi = new CGI;

print

$cgi->header() .
$cgi->start_html( -title => 'Form Results') .
$cgi->center($cgi->h1('Your Reciept <br> Please Print this Reciept')). "\n";

my @params = $cgi->param();
print '<table border="1" width="500" align="center" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">' . "\n";
foreach my $parameter (sort @params) {
    print "<tr><th>$parameter</th><td>" . $cgi->param($parameter) . "</td></tr>\n";
}

print "</table>\n";

#
$ENV{PATH} = "/usr/sbin";

open (MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t ") or &dienice("Can't fork for sendmail: $!\n");
my $recipient = 'test@quickpaysolutions.com, test2@quickpaysolutions.com';
print MAIL "To: $recipient\n";
print MAIL "From: nobody\@quickpaysolutions.com\n";
print MAIL "Subject: Form Data\n\n";
foreach my $p (param()) {
   print MAIL "$p = ", param($p), "\n";
}
close(MAIL);

# Now print a thank-you page

# The dienice subroutine handles errors.

sub dienice {
    my ($errmsg) = @_;
    print "<h2>Error</h2>\n";
    print "<p>$errmsg</p>\n";
    print end_html;
    exit;
}

$cgi->end_html . "\n";
```

Comment: The [documentation for the CGI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) contains very clear warnings like `CGI.pm HAS BEEN REMOVED FROM THE PERL CORE` and `HTML Generation functions should no longer be used`. Your second example also has a `th` element *and* a `td` element in the first `tr`. That is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> *the form confirmation comes out alphabetical and not the way the form is constructed*

That would be because you have

```
foreach my $parameter (sort @params) { ... }
```

If you remove the `sort` then the parameters will appear in the same order as the first example.

But *please understand* that CGI in general and the HTML-generation functions in particular should be avoided, especially for live web sites, which this appears to be. It is a *lot* easier to get something going using [`Dancer2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2)